# Is there a way to make package.json(npm) OS independent (windows/Linux/Mac)?

Tags: reactjs, npm

In my project environment variables are defined in package.json start script which works fine in Mac but not on windows. Is there standard way to make commands OS agnostic?

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "MY_PATH='' MY_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD` react-scripts start",
    "build-local": "MY_PATH='' MY_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD` GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "build-pcf": "MY_PATH=/abcd/web MY_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD` GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Another problem is git commands(ex: git rev-parse --short HEAD) are not parsed in windows unless I point npm shell to bash location. It is a work around.

Comment: how are you defining scripts in package.json, can you also share code the snippet?

Comment: @kritiz I have added code snippet for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

To use env variables the best approach is to use a `.env` document. React will automatically get the variables of that file. You can define your variables this way:

```
SECRET=YOUR_SECRET_HERE
```

This is for development ONLY, because you could leak that information if you deploy your app that way. You can get additional information [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)